# Show/Hide content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jqZoom to swap a main image from selected thumbnail images, but I would also like to toggle some content divs. So when I click on the first thumbnail, it will swap the big image that will have the zoom and also show the content of div id="one". Similarly, clicking thumbnail two would swap

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
            title: false,
            zoomType: 'standard',
            lens:true,
            preloadImages: false,
            alwaysOn:false
        });

});
</script>
[...]
<body>
<div class="clearfix">
    <a href="imgProd/triumph_big1.jpg" class="jqzoom" rel='gal1'  title="triumph" >
        <img src="imgProd/triumph_small1.jpg"  title="triumph"  style="border: 4px solid #666;">
    </a>
</div>
<div id="one" style="display:none;">
    div class one text
</div>
<div id="two" style="display:none;">
    div class two text
</div>
<div id="three" style="display:none;">
    div class three text
</div>
<ul id="thumblist" class="clearfix" >
    <li><a class="zoomThumbActive" href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './imgProd/triumph_small1.jpg',largeimage: './imgProd/triumph_big1.jpg'}"><img src='imgProd/thumbs/triumph_thumb1.jpg'></a></li>
    <li><a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './imgProd/triumph_small2.jpg',largeimage: './imgProd/triumph_big2.jpg'}"><img src='imgProd/thumbs/triumph_thumb2.jpg'></a></li>
    <li><a  href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './imgProd/triumph_small3.jpg',largeimage: './imgProd/triumph_big3.jpg'}"><img src='imgProd/thumbs/triumph_thumb3.jpg'></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the thumbnail links and add some show/hide logic to a `click` event handler for the elements:

```
$('#thumblist').find('a').on('click', function () {
    $('.description').hide().filter('#' + $(this).attr('data-description')).show();
});
```

This code requires that you add the `.description` class to each of your description DIVs and that you add the `data-description` attribute to each thumbnail link, this attribute needs to be set to the ID of the description you want to associate with the link.

```
<div class="description" id="one" style="display:none;">
    div class one text
</div>
<div class="description" id="two" style="display:none;">
    div class two text
</div>
<div class="description" id="three" style="display:none;">
    div class three text
</div>


<ul id="thumblist" class="clearfix" >
    <li><a data-description="one"><img /></a></li>
    <li><a data-description="two"><img /></a></li>
    <li><a data-description="three"><img /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Just getting an error as follows: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: @Arpanet `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`, sorry I normally put that notice on answers.